# Как записать ДатуВремя обновления поля?

Tags: mysql

**Используется:**
- MySQL - 5.7

**Имеется**
**Таблица "Основная":**
- Поле 1 (ДатаВремя) -
- Поле 2. Статус (меняется. Данные из справочника)

**Таблица "Журнал обновлений":**
- таблица содержит состав полей необходимый для журналирования обновлений всех полей основной таблицы.
Заполнение таблицы "Журнал обновлений" осуществляет триггер.

**Вопрос.**
1. Как сделать чтобы при смене статуса в таблице **"Основная"** в **"Поле 1 (ДатаВремя)"** фиксировалось ДатаВремя обновления статуса?
2. Правильно ли будет сделать, чтобы один и тот же триггер прописывал обновления в **"Журнал обновлений"** и потом в таблицу **"Основная"** в **"Поле 1 (ДатаВремя)"**?

Comment: почему бы и нет. трагера для этого и служат. в `before update`, триггере, конечно и обычным присвоением `NEW.датавремя=now()`

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит выносить данные об обновлении записей в отдельную таблицу, попробуйте реализовать запоминание обновления стандартными средствами MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE masssage.profile (
  ....... поля .......
  `updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  ....... поля .......
)
```